# kaminari pagination and activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, activeadmin, kaminari

I have a project that is using Activeadmin and because of that I am using kaminari for pagination in the public parts of the project. All text lead me to believe I should find kaminari partials within my projects app/views/kaminari but I do not see a kaminari dir.

How can I edit the Kaminari partials for only public portion of the project without effecting the activeadmin pagination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just copying the views dir from the gem into my views dir and that worked.